# Springboot security authorities missing in other part of the code

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

In my spring boot application,

After successful login I set the authentication details (with user roles in authorities) in the context

```
    // Perform the authentication
    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    authenticationRequest.getUsername(),
                    authenticationRequest.getPassword()
            )
    );
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

But when I try to access the roles again in other parts of the code with below line the authorities are null. Otherwise, it has all other security details in it.

What am I missing?

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should add the roles when creating the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`, like this:

```java
new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
    authenticationRequest.getUsername(),
    authenticationRequest.getPassword(),
    roles
)
```

This is the signature of the method you should use:

```java
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(Object principal, Object credentials,
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities)
```

Comment: Thanks, but we don't know the user roles before authentication right. They are all stored in Db and available on successful authentication response.

Comment: As far as I understand, when you create a new `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` you are authenticating your user indeed. First match user and pass from DB, if valid, extract roles and then create the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm using a **CustomAuthenticationProvider**... and maybe that's what you also need

Comment: @Jay we know roles before authentication as long as we load user details from db by username. you can skip custom authentication provider if you want as long as you set userdetails service to `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` implementation

Answer (score 0):

> After successful login I set the authentication details (with user roles in authorities) in the context

You should not set authentication details like roles as you mention after successful authentication in the context. I will explain basic flow:

1. Authentication request comes with username and password parameters.
2. UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter will retrieve credentials and create UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username,password), and gives to authenticationmanager.
3. authenticationmanager delegates to appropriate authentication provider which supports  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication request object.(You can have your own authentication provider implementation.)
4. Supporting authentication provider will retrieve user details(**including authorities, not authenticated yet**) by entered username from let's say DB and compares submitted password to retrieved user's password.If success then user details **along with authorities** is passed to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken which would be constructed with 3 arguments like: `new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,null,roles)` which in the constructor sets authentication flag to true.
5. Authentication manager popultates security context with that token(step 4)

So successful login indicates implicitly that roles are there too.
Do you have userDetailsService implementation registered with authentication provider or authentication manager? Would be glad to help you more...