# Get actual user details with spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Actually I´m working in a forum project built with Spring boot, Mongodb and Vue.js.

When I´m trying to post a new comment and get the user datails with the *SecurityContextHolder* and cast it to my UsersDetailImpl who implements from the UserDetails class provided by Spring boot, it throw the following error: **org.springframework.security.web.authentication.webauthenticationdetails cannot be cast to ....  UserDetailsImpl**

I don´t really know the reason of this error becasuse if I test it from Postman does not report an error.

UserDetailsImpl.java

```
public class UserDetailsImpl implements UserDetails {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String id;

private String username;

private String email;

@JsonIgnore
private String password;

private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;

public UserDetailsImpl(String id, String username, String email, String password,
                       Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    this.id = id;
    this.username = username;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.authorities = authorities;
}

public static UserDetailsImpl build(User user) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = user.getRoles().stream()
            .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName().name()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return new UserDetailsImpl(
            user.getId(),
            user.getUsername(),
            user.getEmail(),
            user.getPassword(),
            authorities);
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return authorities;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o)
        return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
        return false;
    UserDetailsImpl user = (UserDetailsImpl) o;
    return Objects.equals(id, user.id);
}
}
```

CommentController.java

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/comments")
public class CommentController {
@Autowired
CommentRepository commentRepository;

@Autowired
RoleRepository roleRepository;

@PostMapping("/ask")
public ResponseEntity<?> ask (@Valid @RequestBody AskRequest askRequest) {

    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();

    HashSet<String> strRoles = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream()
            .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));

    Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
    strRoles.forEach(role -> {
        int cutPoint = role.indexOf("_");
        role = role.substring(cutPoint + 1).toLowerCase();

        findRole(roles, role, roleRepository);
    });

    User user = new User(userDetails.getUsername(),  userDetails.getEmail(), roles);
    ObjectId discussion_id = ObjectId.get();
    String slug =  new Slugify().slugify(askRequest.getTitle());

    Comment comment = new Comment(discussion_id, askRequest.getTitle(),
            askRequest.getText(),slug, "full_slug_test", Instant.now(),user);

    String info = comment.getDiscussion_id().toString() +  comment.getPosted() + comment.getTitle()
            + comment.getText() + comment.getAuthor().getUsername() + comment.getAuthor().getEmail()
            + comment.getAuthor().getId() + comment.getAuthor().getRoles();

    commentRepository.save(comment);

    return ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageResponse(info));
}
}
```

I´m new in all this technologies there may be serious errors. All the advices will be a great help to me because the project is academic.

If someone need more information just ask for it.

Thank you all :)

Answer (score 1):

Change `authentication.getDetails()` to `getAuthentication().getPrincipal()`

You will have:
`UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();`

Comment: The program still throwing the same error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to es.cifpcm.techforum.security.services.authorization.UserDetailsImpl
 at es.cifpcm.techforum.controllers.CommentController.ask(CommentController.java:44)

Comment: This is another problem,my answer  fixes your initial question. Do you store UserDetailsImpl object in security context upon successful authentication?I think you  have custom authentication provider which sets just username as principal instead of your UserDetailsImpl object and this is why you get ClassCastException.

Comment: Sorry I thought it was the same problem. I don't really know so much about Spring Security. I just set an UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken in an Authentication object and then set it into the SecurityContextHolder. I will update my post and remove de front-end code and add more usefull information about sing-in controller and web security configuration. I wait for a respose, thank you.

Comment: Use `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken ` 3 argument constructor  `new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetailsObject,null,userDetailsObject.getAuthorities())` and this as an authentication object is stored in Spring security context holder.. you do not need controller for authentication as authentication is performed at the filter level before request reaches to any controller for protected resource .Read https://stackoverflow.com/a/61018409/10597309 which shows basic flow for authentication, read steps from 1 to 5

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the error and it was in the front-end side. I was sending de headers with the JWT in this way.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import authHeader from './auth-header';

const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/comments/';

class CommentsService {
ask(post){
    return axios.post(API_URL + 'ask', {
        title: post.title,
        text: post.text,
        headers: authHeader()
    });
  }
}
export default new CommentsService();
```

and it is totally wrong so I found the manner to do it.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import authHeader from './auth-header';

const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/comments/';

class CommentsService {
ask(post){
    return axios.post(API_URL + 'ask', {
        title: post.title,
        text: post.text
    },{headers: authHeader()});
  }
}
export default new CommentsService();
```

I also add the code to mount the headers.

```
export default function authHeader() {
let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

if (user && user.accessToken) {
  return { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + user.accessToken };
} else {
  return {};
  }
}
```